# How set an amazon ec2 user to have access to a specific instance only?

Tags: amazon-ec2

How set an amazon ec2 user to have access to a specific instance only?
Can the user to whom I want to give access to a specific instance of my EC2 account be using a separate amazon ec2 account from mine?

Comment: By access are you talking about the ability to use the amazon APIs (StopInstance etc...) or the ability to ssh to that instance?

Comment: Instance specific access can be provided the same way you do for any Linux machine. (or Windows).  Are you talking about Access key to the API?

Comment: I was talking about the amazon API. I don't want to give them the access key. I just want they can log in and be able to make a snapshot of that instance so that they can create it themselves with their own key. But I wouldn't want this user to be able to see anything about my other instances.

Comment: While I am not sure you can limit access to a specific instance, all of the infrastructure permission control is handled by IAM. You may find more information in this documenation: http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/

Comment: Use IAM to set up a restricted user account for them, and use [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to help you set the correct permissions for that user.